# How to set the user for the Google URL Shortener API Quota?

Tags: google-api, google-url-shortener

The Google API console shows a Quota of "1,000,000 queries per day" and "100 queries per 100 seconds per user". Both of these quotas are editable in the console, but the maximum enterable value is 1,000,000 and 100 respectively. I am bumping up against the 100 queries per 100 seconds per user and get a 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded.

[Other Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas) have a parameter "quotaUser" which is an arbitrary string to identify a user which you can apply the above 100 queries per 100 seconds quota to. However, this parameter does not seem to be available to the URL Shortener API and so I am limited to 100 queries per 100 seconds in total which will not meet my needs (and makes the 1,000,000 per day moot).

Is there a way to either raise the quota or send requests as multiple users to get around the quota?

Comment: I have the exact same question. For some reason google makes it very hard.