# How to increase Google URL shortener API Quota

Tags: google-api, google-url-shortener

I cannot find a way to increase the google shortener API beyond the maximum configurable limit of "100 per 100s" (lovely metrics).

I have linked a billing account to the project, I am happy to pay. Not sure how to get Google to take my money and increase the limit?

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553014/how-to-set-the-user-for-the-google-url-shortener-api-quota), but not sure if it is unanswered because of the wrongly worded title, or if this is truly an issue at Google.

Answer (score 0):

This question is now irrelevant, since Google has transitioned from the Google URL shortener to [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/), see corresponding [blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html).